# Is there a Netbeans plugin or issue tracker that provides connectivity to Fogbugz?

Tags: netbeans, plugins, bug-tracking, fogbugz, issue-tracking

I would like to be able to create FogBugz cases directly straight from the editor in NetBeans.  Specifically, I would like to be able to look at a JUnit run in the IDE, examine the failures and create cases directly using the information that is right in front of me (rather than cutting and pasting into a web browser, etc).

I see that NetBeans 6.5.1 ships with Bugzilla available by default and JIRA connectivity in some sort of beta form.  Is there an equivalent FogBugz issue tracker?

*PS: I am aware of the new plugin architecture of FogBugz 7.  However, I have a realistic appreciation of the time that I would be able to commit to creating my own plugin for either NetBeans and / or FogBugz and I suspect that I would be able to make just enough of a partial solution to make my life worse rather than better.*

Answer (score 1):

It appears you may need to write one yourself, as they have plugins for Eclipse and Visual Studio, but not Netbeans.

http://www.fogcreek.com/fogbugz/blog/post/Eclipse-Plugin-For-FogBugz.aspx

Comment: @James Black, yes, I know that's an option.  However, see the PS above: I have a very realistic appreciation for how much time I can scrape together in order to work on a meta-project....

Comment: If you start a version that has some minimum functionality, you can give it to the open-source community, and see if others are interested enough to finish it.  Another option would be to see if some students at a university is looking for a senior design project, and see if that would be acceptable. Or, you could ask Foggy Creek if they can do it. :)

Comment: @James Black, let's be clear, I'm openly hoping that a student looking for a challenge (or player of equivalent level) stumbles on this question and takes it as a dare.  On the flip side, I suspect that Fogcreek would say something along the lines of "that does sound like a good idea.  Best of luck!"  ;-)

Comment: Switch your IDE to Eclipse. :)

Comment: @James: seems like ideal solution :-)

Comment: @Both of you clowns, yes yes, ho ho.  ;-)  Seriously, though, we made the firm decision to support both IDEs that are most popular with people on the team (Eclipse and Netbeans).  This was a huge team-builder, by the way.  I don't like leaving a feature-bias out there if a solution already exists.

Comment: One year passed and nothing changed ? :) I'm quite newbie on bug tracking etc... but I'm starting with netbeans now... just wondering is there's any solution available at present that anyone may know. :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of such plugin. You're right that it is not trivial effort to write full-featured connector, but getting basic one is not that hard ... especially if you're already familiar with NetBeans plugin architecture. If you decide to go for it, take a look at [FogBugz API](http://www.fogcreek.com/FogBugz/docs/70/topics/advanced/API.html) instead of new FogBugz plugins. FogBugz API is used to talk to remote FogBugz repositories.

Comment: @Peter Štibraný, I did take some time to look at the API and I have to say, curse you sir! (in fun, of course)  My immediate thought was "Hey, I could handle this."  Then my reality brain kicked in and reminded me that I have actual paid work to do....  ;-)